# Android : Simultaniously running large amount of animations on single view

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, translate-animation

I've to use like 300+ pair of cords (x, y) and feed them to translate animation to define a unique path for a view on which it could move, is there a way I can have 300+ Translate Animations run one by one on a single view?